# JQuery on submit function

Tags: php, jquery, post, submit

I just have one question regarding JQuery. I need to convert the following piece of code to JQuery syntax,

```
<form id=emailform name=emailform method=POST action=postemail.php onsubmit=doStart();return false>
```

Where `doStart()` is one function in the `PHPUploader` module that uploads multiple
files to the Server.
 
I appreciate your assistance and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post actual code. Use the `{}` markup tool in the SO editor to post it literally.

Comment: You really need to use quotes and correct syntax when writing forms.

Comment: @j.f. Don't fix his bugs when you edit, bug fixes should be in answers.

Comment: @StephanMuller You shouldn't approve a radical change in an edit. See Barmar's comment above about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$('#emailform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStart();
    // could do "return false;" here instead of e.preventDefault() above.
});
```

If that what you mean by converting the code to jQuery.

P.S. I recommend you use double-quotation marks in your HTML code. The HTML line of code you posted should be written something like:

```
<form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="POST" action="postemail.php" onsubmit="doStart();return false">
```

Comment: Thank you my friend for your fast response,  I will test it and give you feedback about the result. Thanks once again.

Comment: Also add `e.stopPropagation()` after `e.preventDefault()` to prevent event bubbling.

Comment: @baph0mt by returning false it will also stop the propagation. BTW, it's not a must in this case

Comment: Just saw that in the comment. Good call. I think that also covers stopImmediatePropagation() as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around the value of an attribute that contains spaces. It's a good idea to quote all attribute values, but if you don't quote it when there's a space, the value will be wrong. Without quotes, the space ends the attribute value. In your case, it was ending with just `return` instead of `return false`.

```
onsubmit="doStart();return false;"
```

Comment: I tested your solution , I noticed that you missed out the "postemail.php", 
so can you please tell me where to put it in your recommended solution. 
I have the following code is working properly but i just need now to add the doStart(); function:-
$.post("postemail.php?"+$("#emailform").serialize(), {
}, function(response){

Comment: I didn't miss it, I just showed the part that you need to change. `action=postemail.php` should work fine, although I recommend putting quotes around the value for consistency.

Comment: Ok let's consider the following working code as I mentioned previously:-
$.post("postemail.php?"+$("#emailform").serialize(), {
}, function(response)
I just want to know where I could put the doStart() function in order to initialize the files uploads
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't try to put code into comments. If there's more to your question, edit the question.